# Copy Files/Folders on Windows Volumes Created from Mac

Tags: rsync, robocopy, migration, xcopy

We are trying to migrate storage from one volume to another, and we are running into problems with folders and files created from Mac OSX.  The current file storage is on windows, and unfortunately some of the users that connect to it from the Mac have named folders ending in spaces "My Folder " or files that end in "." which are not honored on windows, and cannot be copied by programs like robocopy.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how we can easily and cleanly move these files without manually touching all of them?

Comment: If you copy them using the Mac clients themselves does it work?  I wonder if you can move them to a temp location onto a Mac and then move everthing else, then move the files from the temp location onto the new volume.  And then inform the to stop using things that aren't supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx

Comment: The problem is that we are talking about *alot* of files, so we are hoping for some magically scripted way to do this.  Robocopy does seem to move things using the /FAT flag, but I haven't tested yet if we can get permissions to move along with those.

Answer (score 1):

As much of a love affair I have with Robocopy, it won't work for this like you said.  Best way I found around this was to mount the drives on a mac and use "cp" from the terminal using the "-R" recursion tag.

Comment: How would you carry over the windows acl structure then?

Comment: when moving the files, the user that CP is running under would be the owner..  This will simply reset all the ACLs.  I haven't found a way around this.  I have a similar issue copying windows files to our "mac" sandbox..  This is one of those mac vs PC things..  You could write something in VBScript or Powershell to remove the offending entries and simply swap out the " " for an "_" or something.  Might be easier than trying to fight it.  If you are running Windows 2008 R2+ on both you could use DFS-R to replicate them between the boxes...